# Sum miles in only one miles program

Tags: loyalty-programs, airline-alliances

I'm a member of the Executive Club of BA. 
I'd like to understand if I can earn and put together miles form flights of other companies of the One World alliance.

For instance, assume that I have 1000 miles in the Executive Club program. If I'll fly in the future with Iberia (150 miles for the flight) will I be able to claim the miles of Iberia in the Executive Club (and reach 1150)?

Comment: Note that the number of miles that you get may vary by the mileage program you are enrolled in. E.g., for an Air Berlin 300 miles flight, you may get 300 miles credited with Iberia, but only 150 miles if you credit the flight to BA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can earn with partners of the alliance (you'll find the complete list here: http://www.britishairways.com/en-gb/executive-club/tiers-and-benefits/about-tier-points). However, you have to distinguish Avios and Tier points. You can use the calculator at http://www.britishairways.com/travel/flight-calculator/public/en_gb to calculate the exact amount of points.

Comment: Is this valid for whatever alliance? For example, if I am registered in the Lufthansa Miles&More program and I will fly with United (in the same StarAlliance partnership), can I cumulate the miles earned in the United flight in the Lufthansa Miles&More program?

Comment: Basically it depends on the program itself. But most programs allow to collect miles on partners of the same alliance (sometimes even on outside partners, which have special agreements). For your specific example, this is of course possible (either way round).

Comment: Normally you can't move the miles (for instance from BA's Executive Club to American's AAdvantage once they've been credited to your account and you can only collect the miles from each flight on or one OR the other airline's program.